# Valgrind Segmentation Fault

Tags: linux, debian, apt, gcc, segmentation-fault

I've never used Valgrind before and want to use it to check for memory leak in a program written in C. I'm using a BeagleBone AI which run Linux Debian.

```
debian@beaglebone:~$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.14.108-ti-r127 (root@x2-am57xx-beagle-x15-2gb) (gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1)) #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jan 29 04:10:14 UTC 2020
```

I've installed Valgrind.

```
debian@beaglebone:~$ sudo apt-get install valgrind
```

I've compiled my code using gcc. I have two files main.c and main.h.

```
debian@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9/ETS/ELE216/Lab2/mini-shell$ gcc -o main main.c
```

The code run as expected.

```
debian@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9/ETS/ELE216/Lab2/mini-shell$ ./main
```

However, I have an error when I try to run Valgrind. I have the same error no matter the program Valgrind run. I've tried with `ls` and `ps`, I get the same results.

```
debian@beaglebone:/var/lib/cloud9/ETS/ELE216/Lab2/mini-shell$ valgrind --tool=memcheck ./main
==30416== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==30416== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==30416== Using Valgrind-3.12.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==30416== Command: ./main
==30416==

valgrind: m_transtab.c:2459 (vgPlain_init_tt_tc): Assertion 'sizeof(TTEntryC) <= 88' failed.
Segmentation fault
```

I've done some Googling but haven't found anything useful. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like this is a known bug on ARM? https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=362935#c4

Comment: Yes it does look like it. How can I install the latest version of Valgrind? It seems like I need to build it myself but I'll need to learn how to do that.

Comment: Yes you'd either need to build it from source, or upgrade your OS version - for example, it looks like Debian 'Buster" provides [valgrind 3.14](https://packages.debian.org/buster/valgrind)

Comment: I think I'm going to build it from source. All the steps to follow are in the README file that come with the source file. I have one last question, do I need to remove the version of Valgrind currently on my system before doing this?